# how to properly use Mailgun Api via Curl in php

Tags: php, mailgun

I have the curl request below from mailgun which i want to use to create an email list for newsletters on my site.

```
 curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
       https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists \
       -F address='LIST@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME' \
       -F description='Mailgun developers list'
```

**My issues** is that when I run the code below, it shows **invalid private key 401**
It seems that am not setting the api key properly in the curl request. below is my coding so far

```
<?php

$email = 'tmack@gmail.com';
$api_key = 'my key here';
$api = 'api:';
$api_k = $api.$api_key;
$url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists';

$json = json_encode([
    'address' => $email,
    'description'        => 'Tmack group Mailing List'
]);


$ch = curl_init($url);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_k);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
echo $status_code;
```

Comment: Looks like you should use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . $api_k);
`

Comment: Why not just use the SDK? https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

Comment: Thanks that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is what works for me. I just added the code line below

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . $api_k);
```

hence below is the final code

```
$email = 'tmack@gmail.com';
$api_key = 'my key here';
$api = 'api:';
$api_k = $api.$api_key;
$url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/lists';

$json = json_encode([
    'address' => $email,
    'description'        => 'Tmack group Mailing List'
]);


$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . $api_k);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $result;
curl_close($ch);
echo $status_code;
```